# Unbalanced stack error when using GetDiskFreeSpaceExA

Tags: c#, vb.net

The following code (calling proc DiskFreeSpace) throws an "unbalanced stack" error message.

```
Private Declare Function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetDiskFreeSpaceExA" (ByVal lpDirectoryName As String, _
                ByVal lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller As Long, _
                ByVal lpTotalNumberOfBytes As Long, _
                ByVal lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes As Long) As Long

Friend Shared Function DiskFreeSpace(ByVal sdirDrive As String) As Long
            Dim Status As Long
            Dim TotalBytes As Long
            Dim FreeBytes As Long
            Dim BytesAvailableToCaller As Long

            Status = GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(sdirDrive, BytesAvailableToCaller, TotalBytes, FreeBytes)

            Return FreeBytes

        End Function
```

What is wrong here?

The exact error message is:

> A call to PInvoke function
>   'Test!XYZ.Test.FN.MyFileSystem::GetDiskFreeSpaceEx'
>   has unbalanced the stack. This is
>   likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged
>   target signature. Check that the
>   calling convention and parameters of
>   the PInvoke signature match the target
>   unmanaged signature.

Additional note: My function does need to work for UNC paths also (local and/or network).

Comment: This code should’t even compile! Switch on `Option Strict`!

Comment: @Konrad: I agree, but I always have Option Strict set to *On*! It compiles without any error.

Comment: My bad. I hadn’t seen the first parameter in the declaration of the WinAPI function and had assumed that the first parameter’s type was `Long`. And since you passed `sdirDrive` as the first argument, this couldn’t work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem in signature. try to use this ([from pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/GetDiskFreeSpaceEx.html)):

```
<DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetDiskFreeSpaceEx", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
  Private Shared Function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx( _
   ByVal lpDirectoryName As String, _
   ByRef lpFreeBytesAvailable As ULong, _
   ByRef lpTotalNumberOfBytes As ULong, _
   ByRef lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes As ULong) As Boolean
  End Function
```

Difference in returning value

Comment: This function should work with UNC. It was an error in DLL name from which function exported but I fixed this.

Comment: This throws an exception: "Unable to load DLL 'coredll.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)". I'm using Win7/64.

Comment: Yes, now it works :). Can you explain me why my method didn't work (using "Declare Function" instead of "DLLImport" attribute)? I'm already happy enough with the working solution, but just interested to know ;).

Comment: @Marc: I think your method didnt work because of return value and not because of declaration. In your previous edition returning value was `Long` (64bit on .NET) and actually it was passed as Integer (32bit). And diring marshaling Pinvoke always tried to read Long value from stack. So pinvoke in your case had to read extra 32bit of data from stack this was reason of error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about this code but you could also use the code `My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives` and find out the free, used and total space. I feel it is just easier to use the .NET in-built functions rather than trying to use invokes from Windows DLLs because after all a .NET Application will only work on a computer with a .NET Version same or greater than the one on which the application was built!

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that only works for local drives afaik; not for UNC paths. I prefer to avoid using the WinAPI directly, but afaik in this case it seems I have no choice.